# How to insert my django model to postgres?

Tags: django, postgresql

Whenever i change my model and after running makemigrations , there should be changes in the database.
I faced this problem while i was trying to add an user foreign key to my table. no changes were made to the table.
So, I delete my entire table and initial migrations .
and again, i run makemigrations and migrate to transfer my model to postgresql
Ever since , i deleted my model from postgres, I cannot view my table in database.

My migrations

```
Migrations for 'affiliation':
  affiliation\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model ProductView
    - Create model ProductDetails
    - Create model ProductImages
    - Create model AffProduct
```

After this i checked on postgresql server , but no table was created?

Comment: `makemigrations` only makes the migration files, to actually migrate you need to use `migrate` (I assume you only run `makemigrations` after changing your models according to your description)

Comment: i use migrate too, but after i makemigrations and migrate
```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, affiliation, auth, bmedia, contenttypes, product, sessions, signup
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```
This appears and no tables are created on postgresql

Comment: "I delete my entire table" Do you mean you deleted specific tables? Or did you _drop_ the database?

Comment: i delete those specific tables only

Comment: Since you deleted the tables anyway, just drop the database and start over, Django also creates some tables itself, for example `django_migrations` which contains entries that mark which migrations are applied (You likely haven't deleted this), plus many of django's apps also have their own tables. Figuring which tables are deleted etc. would be too tedious, hence just drop the database.

Comment: i tried to drop the database, as its using sessions, I cannot drop the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many different ways.
But like this my problem was solved.

At first , i run
python manage.py migrate --fake <app_name> zero
and then i run,
python manage.py migrate <app_name>.

This should do

Answer (score 0):

With such issues, I'm used to make a systematic check:

1. the settings:

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
       'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
       'USER': os.getenv('DB_USER'),
       'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
       'HOST': 'localhost',
       'PORT': '',
   }
```

2. Then I open PgAdmin and I check the existing DBs and have a look on the existing tables.
3. Sometimes, when I get completely lost, I just delete the DB, create a new one and apply the migrations.
4. If your migrations seem not to be taken into account, I check in the migration files if they have been recorded. If not, I delete the migration and build a new one

Comment: should i consider deleting the app and start it over again?

Comment: Not the app. If you go to your "migrations" folder, you should be able if they take into account the changes in your model.

Comment: Ok. Let me check and view